# Trouble Invoking Move Constructor for Deque with Boost Asio Sockets

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to write a multithreading web server and I'm having a lot of trouble passing accepted `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` objects from my parent thread to my child threads.

My current solution is pretty clanky since I don't think i understand proper class oriented design. Still, I want to get this working with my clanky implementation before I move along and get it cleaner.

Here are the relevant files where the issues are occuring:

```
// consts_globs_shared.h
// User holds a username, and other string related info for this session
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
std::map<
         std::string,
         std::deque<std::tuple<User, tcp::socket, std::deque<std::string>>
         > chan_newusers;
std::mutex newusers_lock;
```

.

```
// server.cpp
#include "consts_globs_shared.h"
...
tcp::socket sock(io_service);
acceptor.accept(sock);       // acceptor defined prior
...

std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(newuser_lock);
if (!chan_newusers.count(channel))
    chan_newusers[channel]; // initialize
chan_newusers[channel].push_back(std::make_tuple(client,
                                                 std::move(sock),
                                                 temp_msgs));
```

.

```
// servlet.cpp
#include "consts_globs_shared.h"
...
for (auto it = chan_newusers[chan].begin(); it != chan_newusers[chan].end(); ++it) {
    tcp::endpoint endpt = std::get<0>(*it).get_endpt(); // Users carry socket endpoint with them since that's copy constructible
    tcp::socket temp(std::move(std::get<1>(*it)));
    // have a class called servlet that holds a map called end_msgs
    // @key: socket endpoints, @value: sockets
    servlet.end_msgs[endpt]; // instantiate
    servlet.end_msgs[endpt] = std::move(temp);
}
```

The idea is that the server grabs incoming connections, moves that socket onto a global map, and then later notifies the child thread managing that chat room that there is a new user that needs to be grabbed. The child thread grabs from the global list. I tried leaving out irrelevant code, but I'm incredibly confused on how to accomplish this.

I think that, when I make the tuple to be pushed onto the deque in the map, the tuple gets copied by value since that's how I believe deques grab new elements, rather than move constructed. So the elements in the tuple are then copied by value, and an attempt is made to copy the socket by value. But I'm not sure how to diagnose if that's what's occuring, nor am I sure how to fix it.

I'd appreciate any advice. And if this post could be made cleaner or easier to understand, please let me know.

EDIT: here is a part of the error I'm getting right now. It's massive but I'll just hone in on what seems most relevant.

```
/usr/include/c++/5/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: use of deleted 
function ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const 
boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp>; _T2 = 
boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>]’
```

.

```
/usr/include/c++/5/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: use of deleted 
function ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const 
boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp>; _T2 = 
boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>]’
```

Answer (score 0):

It would have been helpful if you had included the error message you run into, since your code is not selfcontained.

> I think that, when I make the tuple to be pushed onto the deque in the map, the tuple gets copied by value since that's how I believe deques grab new elements

You're not far of the mark

> , rather than move constructed.

Well. It depends! As you [can see](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/push_back) push_back got a new overload in c++11 accepting an rvalue-reference. If you use it, then definitely, move-construction will happen.

**Note** [c++11 also added `emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/emplace_back) which does the tuple construction in-place

### Sample

I made your sample self-contained, and there are 3 compiling versions that push_back or emplace_back the information:

```
    auto& chan = chan_newusers[channel];
    chan.emplace_back(client, std::move(sock), std::move(temp_msgs));  
    // // ALSO:
    // chan.push_back(NewUserData(client, std::move(sock), std::move(temp_msgs)));  

    // // ALSO:
    // chan.push_back({client, std::move(sock), std::move(temp_msgs)});
```

> **Note** obviously, you can only move once, so uncomment only 1 of the three lines :)

### Full Listing

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c749c11ff4777ad8)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <deque>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>

// User holds a username, and other string related info for this session
struct User {
    std::string name;
    // ...
};

// consts_globs_shared.h
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

using ChannelId = std::string;
using NewUserData = std::tuple<User, tcp::socket, std::deque<std::string>>;

std::map<ChannelId, std::deque<NewUserData> > chan_newusers;
std::mutex newusers_lock;  

struct SomethingInServerCpp {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    void foo() {
        // server.cpp
        //...
        tcp::socket sock(io_service);
        tcp::acceptor acceptor(sock.get_io_service());
        acceptor.bind({{}, 6767});
        acceptor.accept(sock);       // acceptor defined prior
        //...
        User client { "user1" };
        std::string channel = "some_channel_from_the_request_I_guess";
        std::deque<std::string> temp_msgs { "foo", "bar", "qux" };

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(newusers_lock);

        {
            auto& chan = chan_newusers[channel];
            chan.emplace_back(client, std::move(sock), std::move(temp_msgs));  
            // // ALSO:
            // chan.push_back(NewUserData(client, std::move(sock), std::move(temp_msgs)));  
            // // ALSO:
            // chan.push_back({client, std::move(sock), std::move(temp_msgs)});  
        }
    }
};

int main() {
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help!!

I'm going to change it up in that vein and see if it works. I didn't include the error message since it was massive, and for me largely incomprehensible. 

I've been going through a rabbit hole and finding myself pretty confused. The things confusing me now are *placement new*, and *construction in-place* as well as *new* in general I guess. I had understood it as a cleaner malloc, but in the past couple minutes I've noticed it's in fact got a lot more packed into it.

Comment: I'm also pretty confused on the function of `{}` since I had understood it as initialization. I guess if I'm understanding it, based on the three examples you've shown me:

1. emplace constructs an element of type <User, Socket, Deque> and because std::move() is used, those elements are move constructed

2. push_back(&& ) move constructor is invoked, and a NewUserData() call is treated as an rvalue

3. push_back({...}) an object is initialized, and since it's an rvalue the move constructor is invoked

Comment: But my confusion, is if the line where you defined NewUserData is omitted, will these move constructors still get invoked?

Comment: No need to deal with placement new etc. Just use the standard libary ([dont use `new` or `delete`](http://scrupulousabstractions.tumblr.com/post/37576903218/cpp11style-no-new-delete), also [why](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-the-‘new’-and-‘delete’-keywords-considered-bad-in-modern-C++)).

Comment: The use of `{}` is [uniform initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). The first use is [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) of the `User` type; `NewUserData(client, std::move(sock), std::move(temp_msgs))` invokes the variadic constructor if the tuple, and `{client, std::move(sock), std::move(temp_msgs)}` achieves the same using list-initialization syntax. The type for the braced-init-list is [deduced](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Notes)